# Asynchronous communication between microservices and client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices, api-gateway, messagebroker

We have an application based on micro services architecture with the following components

1. Client Application : asp.net core mvc
2. Api Gateway : Ocelot
3. Service A: asp.net core web api

The Client sends request to Service using Restapi via API gateway.
Then the service A  performs some businesss operations, and generates data asynchronously

Now we want to send this generated data asynchronously to the client application and update the UI in real time.
We tried one solution where we directly connect the service A and the client application via message broker : RabbitMQ without involving the API gateway. Does this violate the principle of abstraction between the services and the client in a micro services architecture?

Comment: If you want an asynchronous API and a API gateway, then the API gateway needs to support asynchronous calls. Having an API gateway, but not consistently using it, seem like a terrible idea.

Comment: Can we subscribe to rabbitMQ event in the api gateway published by the Service, and proxy it to the client app?\

Comment: no-one is forcing you to use an API-gateway in a microservice-architecture. However having and and not using it seems indeed a really odd thing. Having said this question is 1. about architectural stuff and should go to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, and 2. even there pretty opinionated.

Comment: My general recommendation regarding microservices is to think long and hard if you really need it. It is mostly designed to solve problems for large systems, where inter team dependencies is an issue, But it will make architectural mistakes harder to fix. So I do not think it is a good fit for small teams doing something new.

Comment: You are making an HTTP Request and it is returning an HTTP Response.  The connection closes after each request/response.  Also the server needs to process the entire message in one chunk so Async does not give any advantage.  That is one reason the enhanced WebSocket was designed which keeps the connection open after each request/response.